# Move /var and /home directory on a separate NVME partition

Tags: debian, mount, directory-structure

I am using Debian 11

I would like to move `/var` and `/home` directories to a NVME partition `nvme1n1p1` I have attached to the server.

EDIT: I am able to move the home folder and bind to the partition. But seems I have not done correctly somewhere. Because I see the read/write speed is not high.

How to do this correctly please? Please note, I am not a Linux expert. This was what I have found online.

```
cd /
sudo fdisk /dev/nvme1n1
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme1n1p1
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /data/
sudo mkdir /data/var/
sudo mkdir /data/home/
sudo rm -rf /data/lost+found


sudo cp -rp /home/* /data/home/
sudo cp -rp /var/* /data/var/
sudo mv /home /home.orig
sudo mv /var /var.orig


sudo mkdir /home
sudo mkdir /var

sudo mount --bind /data/home /home/
sudo mount --bind /data/var /var/

sudo umount /dev/nvme1n1p1
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /data/

sudo nano /etc/fstab

/data/home /home             none rw,bind       0      0
/data/var /var             none rw,bind           0     0

sudo mount -a
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have time for a full answer. The problem is you're mounting `/dev/nvme1n1p1` in two different places but all the files will be the same in both. You should make directories under the `/dev/nvme1n1p1` filesystem (eg. "home" and "var"), then mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 somewhere like /media/nvme1n1p1, then bind-mount the /media/nvme1n1p1/home to /home and /media/nvme1n1p1/var to /var. Or you could use symbolic links instead of bind mounts but the shell acts kind of funny sometimes when your home has a symbolic link in it (it works fine though).You really want /tmp in RAM unless restricted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. I was not mounting the NVME at startup

here's the revised script that I used to solve. Posting in case if anyone needs it.

```
lsblk

sudo -s
cd /
sudo fdisk /dev/nvme1n1
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme1n1p1
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /mnt/
sudo mkdir /mnt/var/
sudo mkdir /mnt/home/
sudo rm -rf /mnt/lost+found


sudo cp -rp /home/* /mnt/home/
sudo cp -rp /var/* /mnt/var/
sudo mv /home /home.orig
sudo mv /var /var.orig


sudo mkdir /home
sudo mkdir /var

sudo mount --bind /mnt/home /home/
sudo mount --bind /mnt/var /var/

sudo blkid /dev/nvme1n1p1
```

(Copy the UUID and use in the fstab command)

```
sudo umount /dev/nvme1n1p1
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1p1 /mnt/

sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Add the following lines in the file:

```
UUID=aa6155a0-2a66-4c3a-977b-4976d47c5eb3 /mnt     ext4    defaults 0   2
/mnt/home /home             none rw,bind       0      0
/mnt/var /var             none rw,bind           0     0

sudo mount -a
```

Explanation:

- We are creating 2 folders in /mnt directory
- then mounting the disk at nvme1n1
- copying all items to 2 folders in /mnt directory
- renaming the original home & var folders
- creating new /home & /var folder at root
- Binding newly created root folder to folders in /mnt
- obtaining UUID for the partition
- adding partition and the mount points in fstab
  DONE!